# Backtrack startx issue

Tags: linux, ubuntu, drivers, vga, backtrack

Downloaded and installed Backtrack 5 R3 Gnome 32 bit into thumbdrive (HBCD). Here is how HBCD menu calls it:

```
title 5) BackTrack\nLinux Distibution for Penetration, Forensics, Hacking, etc.\nOPTIONAL\nNeed to download DVD - Read Instructions
find --set-root /casper/vmlinuz
kernel /casper/vmlinuz file=/preseed/custom.seed boot=casper text splash vga=791-- 
initrd=/casper/initrd.gz
```

[Here are my laptop specs.](http://valid.canardpc.com/show_oc.php?id=2554517)

The problem is, I'm getting following screen everytime when I try to execute `startx` command.

[image]

Comment: No image is linked, can you fix it?

Comment: @nerdwaller I was seeing linked image actually:) Updated question

Comment: Are you on gnome?  If so, try exec gnome-session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a relatively common occurrence when installing to a USB drive, it is caused by xorg.conf being corrupted, or changed. So restoring the failsafe should solve your problem.

First, make a backup of it to be safe:

`sudo cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.bckup`

Then, restore the failsafe:

`sudo cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf.failsafe /etc/X11/xorg.conf`

Full details found here: http://alexsleat.co.uk/2011/03/04/how-to-fix-fatal-server-error-no-screens-found-ubuntu/

Comment: there is no xorg.conf file inside x11 folder. I cd'ed it and tried to see whats inside of this folder by entering dir command: no xorg.conf folder

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/iy8vpebms3qzmm8/2012-10-24%2000.48.26.jpg

Comment: Downvoting is for when an answer is wrong, not when it doesn't work for you. The fact I cited my source should further prove it as useful.

Comment: So using your first screen, check your `/usr/lib/X11/` folder  for `xorg.conf` and modify the commands above, if you do find it there.

Comment: Still wrong https://www.dropbox.com/s/iofvjyfy7u9uo1k/2012-10-24%2001.21.12.jpg

Comment: Updated question. See screenshot